# How to get the parent folder of a Windows user's profile path using C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying get the parent folder of a Windows user's profile path. But I couldn't find any "parameter" to get this using `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`, so far I am using `CSIDL_PROFILE`.

Expected Path:

Win7 -  "C:\Users"

Windows XP -  "C:\Documents and Settings"

Comment: Current user only or possibly another user?

Comment: ex: I am using CSIDL_PROFILE to get the current user path, I am looking similar way to get parent folder of the current user profile path.

Comment: You want the parent path. That threw me off. Also this information about `CSIDL_PROFILE` belongs *into* your question. I fixed that in the question. Please read it and correct it if I got something wrong.

Comment: yes, I am sorry, I will make sure next time before I posting the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>With the shell libary version 6.0 you have the `CSIDL_PROFILES` (not to be confused with `CSIDL_PROFILE`) which gives you what you want.</s> This value was removed (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx)), you have to use your own workaround.

On any prior version you'll have to implement your own workaround, such as looking for the possible path separator(s), i.e. `\` and `/` on Windows, and terminate the string at the last one. A simple version of this could use `strrchr` (or `wcsrchr`) to locate the backslash and then, assuming the string is writable, terminate the string at that location.

Example:

```
char* path;
// Retrieve the path at this point, e.g. "C:\\Users\\username"
char* lastSlash = strrchr(path, '\\');
if(!lastSlash)
  lastSlash = strrchr(path, '/');
if(lastSlash)
  *lastSlash = 0;
```

---

Or of course `GetProfilesDirectory` (that eluded me) which you pointed out in a comment to this answer.

Comment: Thanks@ox0000022l, GetProfilesDirectory also will do the same.

Comment: @JChan: good call, edited it into my answer for completeness. That was probably the reason why `CSIDL_PROFILES` got scrapped so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

For most purposes other than displaying the path to a user, it should work to append `"\\.."` (or `"..\\"` if it ends with a backslash) to the path in question.